# Serial communication on Raspberry Pi - can send data, but cannot read data

Tags: python, serial

I'm using Raspberry Pi 2 to realize RS232 communication between raspberry and my laptop. It seems that my Raspberry Pi can send data, but it can get nothing from my laptop. The following information are about what I've done:

1. I installed a GPIO UART Shield with RS232 on my Raspberry Pi.
2. Edit the file `/boot/cmdline.txt`, and delete the line

*console=ttyAMA0, 115200 kgdbooc=ttyAMA0, 115200*

Edit the file `/etc/inittab`, comment the last sentence:

```
#T0:23:respawn:/sbin/getty -L ttyAMA0 115200 vt100
```

3. Installed python-serial module

In Python 2.7 environment, I tried following commands:

```
import serial
ser=serial.Serial("/dev/ttyAMA0", 9600, timeout=5)
ser.write("hello")
```

On a laptop, I ran a RS232 debug tool. In it, I could directly see the characters "hello". Then, I typed "abcde" on my laptop and pressed "send with every 2 seconds". On Raspberry I executed the following command:

```
ser.read(10)
```

The first time, the data was received, but when I executed the command again, third time, fourth time... nothing was received. The following are the commands I tried, but every time I got " '' "

```
    ser.read(10)

> ''

    ser.readall()

> ''

    ser.inWaiting()

> 0
```

But still, I can use `ser.write()` to send data. And after send, I can read, but only one time.

Then I gave the python environment, and used minicom, but the situation was same:

As long as I typed any characters in minicom, the data could be sent to my laptop immediately. But when I tried to send data from the laptop, at first time, minicom can display the data, then, nothing, and always nothing.

Could anyone tell me what the problem is?

**FURTHER TESTS:**

I found that only after some data was sent by raspberry, it could receive data!
I did following tests:

In raspberry, I executed:

```
>>import serial
>>ser=serial.Serial("/dev/ttyAMA0",9600,timeout=1)
>>ser.write("a")
```

On my laptop, I could receive "a", and I sent "abcde" from my laptop. In respberry I could receive "abcde":

```
>>ser.read(5)
'abcde'
```

Sent "abcde" from laptop again. In raspberry:

```
>>ser.read(5)
'' #Nothing received
>>ser.inWaiting()
0 #Nothing received
>>ser.write("a")
1 #"a" was sent successfully 
>>ser.read(5)
'abcde' #Data received!
```

If I executed `ser.write("")`, still, nothing could be received! It seemed that only after data could be sent successfully, raspberry could read the data! Did any one meet the same situation ?

Comment: I started to edit the format, but realised the post is so full of spelling errors and other carelessness that I don't really know what you mean.

Comment: You should also pass on data format, as in, 5/6/7/8 bytes, No / even / odd parity, 1 / 2 stop bytes. Not sure what the default values are for them.

Comment: How can I pass on data format ?  <br/>Pass these parameters in serial.Serial() function ? Could you give me an example ? Thanks

Comment: What shield?  /dev/ttyAMA0 is TTL (0-3.3V) not RS232 level (-15/15V).  Could you provide details of the shield and a photo of the connections?

Comment: @joan : here is the photo:  <br/>  ![photo](http://pan.baidu.com/s/1sjnAGTf).